# for-each sub-element in collection, Java

Tags: java, foreach

```
for (SubItem i : List<Item>) {
  //do something        
}
```

above construction does not work. I need to use the i-variable multiple times within the loop. My current solution is to make a new, casted, variable in the first line.

```
for (Item i : List<Item>) {
SubItem si = (SubItem) i;
 //do something     
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**
All items in the list are subitems, so I do not have to check instanceOf. Essentially what I want is a method to avoid checking the instance of a class if I have a scrambled collection

Comment: As the list has subitems only then why can't you have List<subItems> instead of List<Item>??

Comment: I could. But I'm in the stupid position in the first place because my school assignment is: "Show that you understand polymorpishm"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast automatically to a more detailed type. You can do the opposite:

```
List<SubItem> subItemList = new ArrayList<SubItem>();
for (Item i : subItemList) {
  //do something        
}
```

In your case you have to cast manually, for example like this:

```
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>(); 
List<SubItem> subItemList = (List) itemList; 
for (SubItem i : subItemList) {
  //do something        
}
```

The cast I do is without generic type on purpose. With the generic type provided (`List<SubItem>`) it wouldn't compile. Keep in mind that you will get a RuntimeException during a cast like that if any element in the `itemList` won't be of type `SubItem`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (SubItem i : List<Item>) {
  //do something        
}
```

This is obviously wrong. You have to use an object of class that supports for each loop and not the class name.

```
List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
for (SubItem i : itemList) {
  //do something        
}
```

Also polymorphism is using super class reference for subclass object and not the other way. So if your list contains Item objects and you need SubItem in your loop you  need to type cast. OR maintain a list of SubItem instead of Item(in generics way).

Comment: The itemList has Items and in the for loop it is subItems???

Comment: I mean when you create the List you provide Items as generics. Then you may add any object to the list whose class extend Item class(SubItem).

Comment: yeah. Thats correct. got it. Your answer signifies this now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
List<Item> itemList = ...;
for (SubItem i : (List<SubItem>)(Object)itemList) {
  //do something        
}
```

generics dont cast with inheritance the same way regular objects do. you can cast a List of Item  to a List of SubItem if you need to. I find i need to cast via an Object to make the compiler accept it. Of course if the list doesn't contain a SubItem it will cause a class cast at the time its selected from the list.  Generics are of course mostly just syntax sugar anyway. Think of them as casts being done under the covers.

Comment: based on Moyshe's answer we can probably get away with a cast via (List) instead of object.